# Prove that non empty set if finite iff there is bijection from A onto finite set B

Tags: real-analysis

Prove that non empty set $A$ if finite iff there is bijection from $A$ onto finite set $B$.

Now assume that A is finite. To find bijection from A $\to B$. How do i find out explicitely such bijection without knowing about B

Thanks

Comment: What is your definition of finite?

Comment: A is said to be finite  if a bijective map exists from A to $N_m$, where $N_m$ ={1,2,3,...,m}

Comment: You don't care *what* the bijection is.  Just that there *is* one.  If B <-> A is a bijection then B is finite.  If the is *no* such bijection for *any* finite set then prove A is not finite.  It will depend on your definitions.  I kind of thought that *was* the definition of finite.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose $A$ is finite. Let $B=A$ and define $f: A \to B$ as $f(x) = x$. Notice $f$ is a bijection from $A$ to a finite set $B$ so we are done.

Conversely, suppose there exists a finite set $B$ and a bijection $f$ from $A$ to $B$. Since $B$ is finite, there exists a bijection $g$ from $B$ to $\{1, 2, \dots, n\}$ where $n \in \mathbb{N}$. Since the composition of bijections is a bijection then $g \circ f$ is a bijection from $A$ to $\{1, 2, \dots, n\}$ and thus $A$ is finite.

Comment: No problem, glad to help :)